# How to use Apollo client properly into Next.js for SSR data fetching?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

In Next.js, I am using getServerSideProps for fetching data:

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {
    const apolloClient = initializeApollo()
    const { data } = await apolloClient.query({
        query: GET_SECTION_LIST,
        variables: { searchInput: {} },
        context: {
            headers: {
                cookie: ctx.req.headers.cookie,
                "user-agent": ctx.req.headers["user-agent"],
                "x-forwarded-for": ctx.req.socket.remoteAddress
            }
        },
        fetchPolicy: "network-only"
    });
    return addApolloState(apolloClient, {
        props: {},
    })
}
```

I need realtime on every request, that's why I use network-only as fetch policy. Here be note that, I also need the page SSR render with fetched data and I also need realtime data when I navigate internally into Next.js. As the video I give, I have some section data, I go the group page. Suddenly I delete a section data from databse. And then I go to the section page again, here it should update the data, as I use network-only as fetch policy. But getServerSideProps function fetching the update data, then why Apollo client not update the previous cached?

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/78312010/242200534-d5106c4d-2df1-49ae-854c-c1b5633402c0.mp4

Here is my code:

`client.ts`:

```
import { useMemo } from "react";
import {
    ApolloClient,
    InMemoryCache,
    type NormalizedCacheObject,
} from '@apollo/client';
import merge from 'deepmerge';
import isEqual from 'lodash-es/isEqual';

const COUNTRIES_API = 'http://localhost:3001/ecampus';

const APOLLO_STATE_PROP_NAME = '__APOLLO_STATE__';

let apolloClient: ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject> | null;

function createApolloClient() {
    return new ApolloClient({
        ssrMode: typeof window === 'undefined',
        uri: COUNTRIES_API,
        cache: new InMemoryCache(),
        credentials: 'include'
    });
}

export function initializeApollo(initialState?: any) {
    const _apolloClient = apolloClient ?? createApolloClient();

    if (initialState) {
        const existingCache = _apolloClient.cache.extract();

        const data = merge(initialState, existingCache, {
            arrayMerge: (destinationArray, sourceArray) => [
                ...sourceArray,
                ...destinationArray.filter((d) =>
                    sourceArray.every((s) => !isEqual(d, s))
                ),
            ],
        });
        _apolloClient.cache.restore(data);
    }

    if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
        return _apolloClient;
    }

    if (!apolloClient) {
        apolloClient = _apolloClient;
    }

    return _apolloClient;
}

export function addApolloState(
    client: ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject>,
    pageProps: any
) {
    if (pageProps?.props) {
        pageProps.props[APOLLO_STATE_PROP_NAME] = client.cache.extract();
    }

    return pageProps;
}

export function useApollo(pageProps: any) {
    const state = pageProps[APOLLO_STATE_PROP_NAME];
    const client = useMemo(() => initializeApollo(state), [state]);
    return client;
}
```

`_app.tsx`:

```
export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const apolloClient = useApollo(pageProps);
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={apolloClient}>
      <main className={`${inter.variable} font-sans`}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </main>
    </ApolloProvider>
  )
}
```

And in one component of my page:

```
const sectionsData = useQuery<GetSectionListData>(GET_SECTION_LIST, { variables: { searchInput: {} } });
```

Here is my full code: https://github.com/siamahnaf/apollo-test